# ¿Cómo hacer combos dependientes en AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

¡Hola! Estoy creando combos dependientes a partir de `JSON`; este arreglo lo genero desde `JPA` a su vez desde `ORACLE` que me devuelte un arreglo en formato `JSON`. Les explico brevemente: tengo dos tablas en BDD (`cEntidad` 1:N `cUnidadAdministrativa`). Ahora lo que quiero es que cada vez que seleccione el combo de cEntidad obtenga las ENTIDADES (Entidad 1, Entidad 2 etc) y de acuerdo a sus Foreign Key me devuelva las UNIDADES ADMINISTRATIVAS, ejemplo:

**ENTIDAD 1 >
         (UNIADM 1
         UNIADM 2
         UNIADM 3)**

**ENTIDAD 2 >
         (UNIADM 4
         UNIADM 5
         UNIADM 6)**

Lo que llevo programado lee el primer array y compara con los coincidentes en el segundo, pero me cicle y creo solo falta guardarlo en un array y ese meterlo en el segundo combo, para que que recupere el modelo, saludos y espero me puedan ayudar, gracias

```js
// Code goes here


var app = angular.module("app", []);
 
app.controller("PruebaController", function($scope) {
  $scope.modelo;
  $scope.selects;
  
  $scope.cEntidad=[
    {"cscEntidad":1,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 1","snActivo":1},{"cscEntidad":2,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 2","snActivo":1},{"cscEntidad":3,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 3","snActivo":1},{"cscEntidad":4,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 4","snActivo":1},{"cscEntidad":5,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 5","snActivo":1},{"cscEntidad":6,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 6","snActivo":1},{"cscEntidad":7,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 7","snActivo":1},{"cscEntidad":8,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 8","snActivo":1},{"cscEntidad":9,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 9","snActivo":1},{"cscEntidad":10,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 10","snActivo":1}
  ];
  
  $scope.cUnidadAdministrativa=[
    {"cscUnidadAdm":1,"chrDescripcion":"UA 1","snActivo":1,"centidad":{"cscEntidad":1,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 1","snActivo":1}},{"cscUnidadAdm":2,"chrDescripcion":"UA 2","snActivo":1,"centidad":{"cscEntidad":1,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 1","snActivo":1}},{"cscUnidadAdm":3,"chrDescripcion":"UA 3","snActivo":1,"centidad":{"cscEntidad":2,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 2","snActivo":1}},{"cscUnidadAdm":4,"chrDescripcion":"UA 4","snActivo":1,"centidad":{"cscEntidad":2,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 2","snActivo":1}},{"cscUnidadAdm":5,"chrDescripcion":"UA 5","snActivo":1,"centidad":{"cscEntidad":3,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 3","snActivo":1}},{"cscUnidadAdm":6,"chrDescripcion":"UA 6","snActivo":1,"centidad":{"cscEntidad":3,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 3","snActivo":1}},{"cscUnidadAdm":7,"chrDescripcion":"UA 7","snActivo":1,"centidad":{"cscEntidad":4,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 4","snActivo":1}},{"cscUnidadAdm":8,"chrDescripcion":"UA 8","snActivo":1,"centidad":{"cscEntidad":4,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 4","snActivo":1}},{"cscUnidadAdm":9,"chrDescripcion":"UA 9","snActivo":1,"centidad":{"cscEntidad":5,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 5","snActivo":1}},{"cscUnidadAdm":10,"chrDescripcion":"UA 10","snActivo":1,"centidad":{"cscEntidad":5,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 5","snActivo":1}}
  ];
  
      $scope.getUA = function () {
        //console.log("Entidad o Dependencia:" + $scope.cEntidad);
        //alert("Entidad o Dependencia:"+ $scope.modelo.CEntidad);

        for (var i in $scope.cUnidadAdministrativa) {
          
            if ($scope.modelo.CEntidad === $scope.cUnidadAdministrativa[i].centidad.cscEntidad) {
                //alert($scope.modelo.CEntidad);
                
                var array = $scope.cUnidadAdministrativa[i];
                console.log("Descripcion  :"+ array.chrDescripcion);// Unidades Administrativas a las que le pertenecen a Entidad
                //alert("selects: "+ array.chrDescripcion);
                
            }
            
        }
          //$scope.newSelects = $scope.selects;
        //alert("newSelects; "+$scope.newSelects.cscUnidadAdm);
        $scope.selects = array;
       return $scope.selects; 
     }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="PruebaController">

      <select ng-model="modelo.CEntidad" id="cscEntidad" ng-change="getUA()" ng-options="option.cscEntidad as option.chrDescripcion for  option in cEntidad" >
        <option value="">--Elige opcion--</option>
      </select>
      <select ng-model="modelo.CUnidadAdministrativa" ng-options="option.cscUnidadAdm as option.chrDescripcion for option in selects.chrDescripcion" >
        <option value="">--Elige opcion--</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      El id de la entidad seleccionada es: {{modelo.CEntidad}} 
      <br>
      <br>
      El array de la UA seleccionada es: <br>{{selects}}
      
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Según entiendo, quieres hacer una petecion al servidor cuando elijas una entidad, o la peticion ya esta hecho, y tienes el objeto alli?

Comment: La peticion ya esta hecha, tengo una vista que tiene esos dos arreglos y  solo los recupero con el index, ya sea cUnidad o cUnidadAdmin, pero como tengo demaciados datos, solo puse dos array de ejemplo con algunos datos, espero haberme explicado.

Comment: este objeto `{"cscUnidadAdm":2,"chrDescripcion":"UA 2","snActivo":1,"centidad":{"cscEntidad":1,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 1","snActivo":1}}`, es el que debe cargar en el select?

Comment: Este Objeto `{"cscEntidad":1,"chrDescripcion":"ENTIDAD 1","snActivo":1}` carga el primer select y este `{"cscUnidadAdm":2,"chrDescripcion":"UA 2","snActivo":1,"centidad":{"cscEntidad":1,"chrDescripcion":‌​"ENTIDAD 1","snActivo":1}}`  carga el segundo select, como puedes observar el segundo object contiene la informacion de a cuales entidades pertenece.

Comment: si pero mi pregunta, va a que si es ese el que quieres mostrar, en mi caso, elegí la primera entidad del primer **select**, y me cargo eso, ejecutando el código que tu pusiste

Comment: Si es lo que quiero, lo que me faltaria es: supongo yo, guardar ese nuevo objeto que recibo de cUnidadAdministrativa y meterlo en el segundo select.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53710/discussion-between-hugo-vazquez-and-pedro-miguel-pimienta-morales).

Comment: Por favor no agregues textos como "[resuelto]" en el título. Aceptar una respuesta es suficiente para verlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error esta al filtrar los de ENTIDAD X el array solo guarda el ultimo. Deberías ponerlo así...

```
    $scope.getUA = function () {
           var array = [];
           for (var i in $scope.cUnidadAdministrativa) {

                  if ($scope.modelo.CEntidad === $scope.cUnidadAdministrativa[i].centidad.cscEntidad) {
                       array.push($scope.cUnidadAdministrativa[i]);                
                  }            
          }
          $scope.selects = array;
          return $scope.selects; 
   }
```

Ya teniendo eso, solo modifica esto en el html...

```
     <select ng-model="modelo.CUnidadAdministrativa" ng-options="option.chrDescripcion for option in selects" >
```

Espero te ayude...
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpGQga?editors=1010

Comment: ¡Chingón!. Créeme que justo ahora estaba viendo esa función `push`, y si en efecto solo guardaba el ultimo, muchas gracias caballero.

Comment: Que bueno que te resolvió, un detalle en lugar de usar un array podrías usar solo el `$scope.selects = []` y  hacer el push directamente.